# How to calculate occurrences of some word in table

Tags: microsoft-excel, sorting

How can I calculate how many times occurrences any of these "value"
[Column](http://www.dodaj.rs/f/2k/Gt/3ZKWTYC9/snap167.jpg)
for example I need:

```
N 97    5
N 72    7
N 83    22
N 70    3
N 76    8
Z 34    7
N 85    2

...
...
...
```

and sorted alphabetically

Comment: Use a pivot table.

Answer (score 0):

Use Text to Columns to parse the data into multiple columns. After that, you can use a PivotTable or the COUNTIF command to do a count of your data.

Here's a brief link on the Text to Columns command: http://www.techrepublic.com/article/the-fastest-way-to-parse-text-in-excel/